# GET request with jQuery not working in DJango

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to do a simple post deleting in django , 
the problem is my view function that should be using the data from the request.GET is not even being called ( not sure though :( )

here's my code :

view.py :

```
@login_required
def delete_blog(request) :
    idNum = None
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        idNum = request.GET['GET_ID']

    if idNum :
        obj = AuthPost.objects.filter(id=idNum) 
        obj.title = "" # i know it should delete it , not just change the title , only did this for test 
        obj.save()
    return HttpResponse("test") #again , just for testing purposes , should return something more valuable i suppose ! :)
```

urlCONF :

```
url(r'^blog/delete_blog/' , delete_blog , name='delete_blog' ) ,
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*alert("js working") ;*/

    $('.delete').click( function(){
        var idNum ;
        idNum = $(this).attr('data-id') ; /* each button has a data-id attribute , this part works fine */ 
        alert(idNum) ; /* everything is fine , till here , the alert call outputs the correct id */ 
        $.get('/blog/delete_blog/' , {GET_ID : idNum} , function (data) {
            alert(data) ; /* nothing happens here */ 
        }) ;
        $(this).hide(1000) ;
    }) ;
}) ;
```

and in the end , when i click on some button with class="delete" , page will alert the id of that post , and ... that's about it , nothing else , seems like the view delete_post(request) is ignored .
Thanks :)

UPDATE : 
a line from /.manage.py runserver log might be helpful here :

```
"GET /blog/delete_blog/?GET_ID=5 HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: If you do a network capture do you see the `GET` ajax call? Also, are you using a get to delete? That should be a post for a bunch of reasons, a get shouldn't change data

Comment: @Prescott Correct , i was so busy bumping my head to wall i forgot POST is the proper way to modify database , but as you see in the example , i don't even expect anything to change , i don't think POST or GET is the problem here

Comment: What does your browser dev tools show as the request / response for this call? I see it's hitting the server from your log, but what is it responding with?

Comment: You need to add de CSRF token to the jQuery request https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ also you should use forms.py to handle your form validation. Because that looks like PHP and Python/Django uses MTV :)

Comment: what is the HTML type of the `button` ? If it is a `a` or `type="submit"`, you would have to prevent the default action from occuring.

Comment: Was this resolved? How? I'm on the same page